# Django For loop inside another for loop in template file

Tags: django, loops, for-loop

have two models; student and hobbies.Every student can have multiple hobbies and Using templates i can make the for loop for first model fine, but I could not make the nested loop for the second model inside templates.
I have tried to write the for loop inside views.py file but it is only return the first n only? i do not know why
(I want to show in template every student list and inside each student another list for hobbies related to that student number)
models.py:

```
class student(models.Model):
   studentNumber = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   studentName = models.CharField()


class hobbies(models.Model):

  studentNumber = 
  models.ForeignKey(student,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
  hobby = models.CharField()
```

views.py:

```
def hobbyList(request):

   b = student.objects.all()
   c = hobbies.objects.(filter=studentNumber=n) ## here is the problem the n

   return render(request,'student/hobby.html',{'b':b,'c':c})
```

template file:

```
<ul>
 {% for n in b %}
 <li>{{ n.studentNumber }}
   <ul>
    {% for s in c %}
     <li>{{ s.hobby }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>
 </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on Django documentation finaly I found the answer by using REGROUP filter in templates.
for details: here is the link form Django doc [regroup filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)